# Where did the phrase "drop the hammer" come from?

Tags: etymology, expressions

Where did the phrase "drop the hammer" come from? It's what you do when you start to go balls to the wall.

I've only heard it rowing.

Comment: And what does "start to go balls to the wall" mean? When explaining what an idiom means, it's probably best to not use another one!

Comment: I agree- but in this case I can't think of any other way to define it.

Comment: I'd like to see what references you have used where these expressions are explained. *Drop the hammer* has other meanings than the one you referred to. There is quite a lot to be learned about what it means before you start asking where did it come from.

Comment: Hm... all I can give you is that it's a common phrase in rowing. I've never heard it used elsewhere. Sorry.

Comment: The technical definition can be looked up, so here are the links to the US governing body and the world governing body so you can get a sense of what the sport is: http://usrowing.org/index.aspx

and http://www.worldrowing.com/

Comment: The nice thing about having ELU at your fingertips is that you also have the rest of the internet within your reach, also. Try doing some research with just the expression, and forget about rowing. You will generally get a lot more help here if you show some initial effort or some sort. Otherwise, you have a strong chance of having your question closed for being a general reference question where the answer can be easily obtained from readily available resources.

Comment: A search of *drop the hammer* yields several related definitions such as [this one](http://www.definition-of.com/drop+the+hammer). There are also links to [supposed etymologies](https://nz.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071111210044AAD3NDY). If you want more from us, you need to cite why these don't suffice.

Comment: I've searched in the past, but come up with nothing, which is why I asked here.

Comment: @Bib- that looks like exactly what I was looking for. Now I'm embarrassed that I didn't find it myself :(

Comment: Bib: why don't you bump up your comment to an answer so I can approve it and close this question out.

Comment: I've heard it used in an office setting. 'Time to drop the hammer' means it's quitting time. The allusion is to a worker at a bench who uses a hammer, e.g., a cobbler.

Comment: When I or my coworkers said "it's hammer time" at the end of the day, it meant time to go out for drinks. Or else it's just time to get hammered ! Either way, not the same as "drop the hammer".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've only ever seen it as described in [definition-of.com](http://www.definition-of.com/drop+the+hammer): "Bringing a pending act to fruition. Usually connotes an act which will have serious consequences" and always as a one-time act which will bring all force to bear.

Also, like [loufedalis' answer given in Yahoo! Answers](https://nz.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071111210044AAD3NDY), I believe the origin to be military and related to the hammer of a cocked pistol or rifle.  When you pull the trigger and drop the hammer that certainly fits the poetic description of someone waiting for the right moment to strike with all available force.

Answer (score -1):

From Wikipedia...in Reference to repairing the clock "Big Ben" in London...."3–4 June 1941: The clock stopped from 10:13 p.m. until 10:13 the following morning, after a workman repairing air raid damage to the clock face dropped a hammer into the works.[19]"
Or another saying it resembles..."Put a spanner in the works"???

Comment: This answer is a literal meaning and does not answer the original poster's question of the idiomatic meaning.

Answer (score -5):

This must be a reference to **Thor's hammer**! Thor was a major Norse god who wielded a fearsome hammer, which was his weapon of choice. He was the god of thunder, and his mighty hammer called "*Mjollnir*" was forged by dwarves. When Thor did battle, he **dropped the hammer** on his foes. When people heard thunderstorms they knew it was the sound of his powerful hammer crashing down on his enemies.

So to "drop the hammer" is to go all-out, or give it your all (balls to the walls).

Comment: This is very imaginative. However, I downvoted this post because I don't think that it's true, and I don't think false answers are useful even if they are amusing. If you have any convincing evidence that this is the real etymology of this phrase, please edit your post to add references.

Comment: While your balls to the wall definition is colorful you didn't cite a source, which you might find in the American comic book, but I don't see how this relates to English Usage, as in the North (Norway) they do not speak English as their first language but one of two forms of Norweigen instead (one of which is thought to be a fey dialect).